# Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object - startActivity

Tags: android, parcelable, serializable

I'm trying to create a registration system. I declare an instance of Profile one time in the first activity, then I use this same instance to pass to another activity. I already passed the same object over 4 times to others activities, but there's one that gives this error.

Class call:

```
btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            newUser.setProfilePic(pic);
            Intent itt = new Intent(Register20.this, Register30.class);
            Bundle bd = new Bundle();
            bd.putSerializable("newUser", newUser);
            itt.putExtras(bd);
            startActivity(itt);
            Register20.this.finish();
        }
    });
```

Class that receives:

```
public class Register30 extends AppCompatActivity {

Profile newUser = new Profile();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register30);
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
    newUser =  (Profile)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("newUser");
}
```

}

My custom object class (I didn't put getters and setters to not get too big):

```
public class Profile implements Serializable{

private String name;
private Integer age;
private String sex;
private String description;
private Calendar dateOfBirth;
private String password;
private String emailRegistration;
private int numberCellRegistration;
private ArrayList<Profile> friends = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Like> likes = new ArrayList<>();
private ImageView profilePic;
```

}

Exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.chest.chestbrasil.chest, PID: 8880
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.chest.chestbrasil.chest.Profile)
   at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1468)
   at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1416)
   at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:686)
   at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1330)
   at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1079)
   at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:711)
   at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:7804)
   at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2677)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1574)
   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3921)
   at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:50)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:79)
   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3881)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:859)
   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4208)
   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4176)
   at com.chest.chestbrasil.chest.Register20$2.onClick(Register20.java:73)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201)
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21163)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1344)
   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1651)
   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1461)
   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:959)
   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:360)
   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1054)
   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1384)
   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1651)
   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1461)
   at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1463)
   at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1416) 
   at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:686) 
   at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1330) 
   at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1079) 
   at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:711) 
   at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:7804) 
   at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2677) 
   at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1574) 
   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3921) 
   at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:50) 
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:79) 
   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3881) 
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:859) 
   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4208) 
   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4176) 
   at com.chest.chestbrasil.chest.Register20$2.onClick(Register20.java:73) 
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201) 
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21163) 
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either:

- Remove `profilePic` from `Profile`, or
- Change it to some data type that can be passed across process boundaries and is not too large (e.g., a resource ID), or

An `ImageView` cannot be passed across process boundaries, and every `startActivity()` call passes the `Intent` from your process to a core OS process (and, in this case, back to your process). Instead, pass something that can tell you how to populate some other `ImageView` in the `Register30` `Activity`.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'll search for something to do that.

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException:
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView

The ImageView is not Serializable. You should, instead, pass the byteArray that contains the given image on your model and recreate it on the `onCreate` method.